# Nginx Slow/Failing requests when hosting multiple sites

Tags: nginx

I think this is somewhat of an interesting issue, and being new to nginx I'm not sure what configuration I need to look at to resolve this. I am hosting two web applications using the nginx reverse proxy. If a request comes in looking for myapp1.com it will route them to my app hosted at 127.0.0.1:3000, if they request myapp2.com it will route them to my app hosted at 127.0.0.1:3001. The problem is when I try to hit both of them in a relatively short amount of time (IE: hit http://myapp1.com and http://myapp2.com in browser). It will usually serve the first one up and then the request for the other will take too long and fail. Whats going wrong with nginx? Below are my configuration files.

**Edit:**
After connecting to a VPN this issue does not happen. Is this an issue because I am on the same LAN connection with the host? Is there any way to get around that?

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        log_format main_ext '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                                '"$host" sn="$server_name" ' 'rt=$request_time '
                                'ua="$upstream_addr" us="$upstream_status" '
                                'ut="$upstream_response_time" ul="$upstream_response_length" '
                                'cs=$upstream_cache_status' ;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main_ext;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  myapp1.com www.myapp1.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  myapp2.com www.myapp2.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever resolve this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @SebastienDesemberg it was a DNS issue for me, so the problem was that my computer had trouble routing to my local DNS from the external IP. So the fix to this is either to set up a local dns server (which did not work for me) or edit the hosts file on the computer. I now just edit the hosts file on all my machines that I use and redirect to local IP's on my LAN.